# Typescript call static method of generic type

Tags: generics, typescript, service, static

I have a service which I want to use to return a object of a specified type build from a JSON.

I have a class `MyClass` which implements a static class which define a `FromJSON` static method.

```
export interface InterfaceMyClass {
    static FromJSON(json: any): any;
}

export class MyClass implements InterfaceMyClass {

    constructor(){}

    FromJSON(json: any): MyClass {
        let instance = MyClass.create(MyClass.prototype);
        Object.assign(instance, json);
        // Some other code specific to MyClass
        return instance;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to call the static method of the generic class that I've passed in parameter in my service.
My service looks like this:

```
export class MyService<T extends InterfaceMyClass> {
    getObject() {
        let json = getExternalJson(...);
        return T.FromJSON(json); // <-- How to call static method FromJSON from T class ?
    }
}
```

I would like to use the service this way:

```
let service = new MyService<MyClass>();
let myObject = service.getObject(); // <-- Should by an MyClass instance (created by MyClass.FromJSON)
```

**Question:**
How can I call this `T.FromJSON` method?

**Bonus question:** What is the good way to implements static method? I dont think that my `FromJSON` method from `MyClass` is static. If I add static word before `FromJSON`, it tells me this:

```
[ts] Class 'MyClass' incorrectly implements interface 'InterfaceMyClass'.
       Property 'FromJSON' is missing in type 'MyClass'.
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A few things:

(1) Interfaces can't have static declarations, for example:

```
interface MyInterface {
    static myMethod(); // Error: 'static' modifier cannot appear on a type member
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20MyInterface%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20myMethod()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20'static'%20modifier%20cannot%20appear%20on%20a%20type%20member%0A%7D))

The way to get around this in typescript is to define a builder/constructor interface:

```
interface MyInterface {}

interface MyInterfaceBuilder {
    new (): MyInterface;
    myMethod();
}
```

(2) Generic constraints are only available in compilation time, but then the compiler removes them as javascript doesn't support it, for example:

```
class MyClass<T extends string> {
    private member: T;

    constructor() {
        this.member = new T(); // Error: Cannot find name 'T'
    }
}
```

compiles into:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        this.member = new T(); // Error: Cannot find name 'T'
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20string%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20member%3A%20T%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.member%20%3D%20new%20T()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Cannot%20find%20name%20'T'%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

When looking at the js output it's clear why the compiler throws the `Cannot find name 'T'` error, as `T` is nowhere to be found.

To get around all of that, here's a solution for you:

```
interface IMyClass {}

interface IMyClassBuilder<T extends IMyClass> {
    new (): T;
    FromJSON(json: any): any;
}

class MyClass implements IMyClass {
    static FromJSON(json: any) {
        return "";
    }
}

class MyService<T extends IMyClass> {
    private classToCreate: IMyClassBuilder<T>;

    constructor(classToCreate: IMyClassBuilder<T>) {
        this.classToCreate = classToCreate;
    }

    getObject(): T {
        let json = getExternalJson(...);
        return this.classToCreate.FromJSON(json);
    }
}

let service = new MyService(MyClass);
let myObject = service.getObject();
```

([code in playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IMyClass%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IMyClassBuilder%3CT%20extends%20IMyClass%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20()%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FromJSON(json%3A%20any)%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20implements%20IMyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fn()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20FromJSON(json%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyService%3CT%20extends%20IMyClass%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20classToCreate%3A%20IMyClassBuilder%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(classToCreate%3A%20IMyClassBuilder%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.classToCreate%20%3D%20classToCreate%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getObject()%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20json%20%3D%20getExternalJson(...)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.classToCreate.FromJSON(json)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20service%20%3D%20new%20MyService(MyClass)%3B%0D%0Alet%20myObject%20%3D%20service.getObject()%3B))

Comment: I wonder if there could be any way to write this so you could do `new MyService<MyClass>()` instead of `new MyService(MyClass)`